# Computing for the mean of a given column from a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I need to find the arithmetic mean of each columns by returning res?

```
def ave(df, name):
    df = {
    'Courses':["Spark","PySpark","Python","pandas",None],
    'Fee' :[20000,25000,22000,None,30000],
    'Duration':['30days','40days','35days','None','50days'],
    'Discount':[1000,2300,1200,2000,None]}

#CODE HERE
res = []
for i in df.columns:
    res.append(col_ave(df, i))


I tried individually creating codes for the mean but Im having trouble
```

Comment: sorry, don't understand. how did you try df[name].mean()

Comment: What is the point of your `ave` function? Why does it take a `df` parameter but immediately overwrites it by hardcoding a DataFrame? What is the expected output given you have non numeric columns?